# Change a rails engine method name in multiple rails clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

We need to change to occurrences of a method that is in our API (A rails engine) in multiple clients. Not a fantastic place to be. I was wondering if there is a easier way to do this ? I am considering using an regex but though that commands on a new line could throw this approach.

Basically

```
retention.group_by('bla').count
```

needs to be changed to

```
retention.group_by('bla').size
```

This only applies to objects that are returned by the group_by, there are other occurrences of count on other objects which should not be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you're looking for : `(\.group_by\(.+\)\.)(count)`.
Then you need to replace your match by `"$1size"`.

To apply the replacement on the file "my_file" in bash :

```
sed -i "s/(\.group_by\(.+\)\.)(count)/$1size/g" my_file
```

(I'm not really sure about the bash syntax, but I'm quite sure about the regular expression itself)

EDIT : To make sure you don't match any `count_unique`, you can use `(\.group_by\(.+\)\.)(count)([^_])` and replace it by `$1size$3`

Comment: for bonus marks how to exclude count_unique from the results ? Its being incorrectly changed atm

Comment: I edited my answer to write a regex which makes sure you don't match any '_' after 'count'

Answer (score 0):

Ruby mine find and replace using regexes to the rescue

[image]